# On existence of holomorphic function with prescribed properties

Tags: complex-analysis

So the question is over existence of a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}_*$ = $\mathbb{C}$\{0} for which |$f(z)$| $\geqslant$ $e^{\frac{1}{|z|}}$ . I should somehow use Cauchy's inequality for coefficients or zero theorem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.com. Could you provide a more descriptive form of the "zero theorem"?

Comment: So, I mean the ( I don’t know it’s name on English) “identity theorem” which is simple corollary from theorem of isolated zeros. (Small hint: this theorem should be applied to $\frac{1}{f}$ in my problem)

Comment: This is not an enlgish issue, it is more of a theorem having many possible names or none at all in which case it is better to partially (or completely) state the theorem in question.

Comment: I’ll state it here (because I can’t edit my question anymore) . We have two holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ in some domain D. We also have the set E = { z $\in$ D | $f(z)$ = $g(z)$ } which contains non-isolated point then $f \equiv g$ in D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there is no such function $f:D'\to\Bbb C$, where $D'=\{z:0<|z|<1\}$.

The function $g=1/f$ has a removable singularity at the origin, with $g(0)=0$. If $g$ has a zero of order $N$ at the origin then there exist $c$ and $\delta$ with $$|f(z)|\le c|z|^{-N}\quad(0<|z|<\delta).$$

Comment: I can’t get last step. So I know, if $g$ has a zero of order $\mathit{N}$ then $g(z) = c_Nz^N+...$ in some neighborhood of origin. After that you simply get $|1/f| = |c_Nz^N +...$ So from now I can’t get you last step. Can you please explain that? Thank you

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO Hint: Take that power series for $g$ and factor out $z^N$: $g(z)=z^Nh(z)$, where $h$ is holomorphic and $h(0)\ne0$. Hence $|h(z)|\ge c>0$ near the origin...